# Server error occurred when using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

We've worked out all the bugs along the way right down to this server error on the last function of the app script. The script is to send an email alert to a guest booking.

The code specifically breaks on the `mailapp` function (line 27). Any input would be appreciated!

```
function sendEmail() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()[0];
  var startRow = 1;  
  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 11;   
  // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, 12, numRows, 11);
  //Assigning spreadsheet feilds
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
 var firstName = row[1];
 var guestFirstN = row[6]; 
 var guestLastN = row[7];
 var arrivalDate = row[8];
 var numberNights = row[9];
 var rmName = row[10];
 var recipient = row[11]; 
 //email data
 var subject = "IMPORTANT: Your Roommate Has Requested An Overnight Guest!";
 var message = "Your roommate" + firstName + "has requested that" + guestFirstN + "stay as a guest in your residence room on" + arrivalDate + "for" + numberNights + "." + "<br> If you do not agree to have" + guestFirstN + "stay in your residence room please contact the front desk as soon as possible. <br> Not contacting the front desk with adequate notice will give implied consent to the guest staying."; 
    MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: recipient,
  subject: subject,
  message: message,
});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using MailApp class as the following :

```
// MailApp.sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)  

MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com",
               "replies@example.com",
               "TPS report status",
               "What is the status of those TPS reports?");
```

or change `message` with `body` in your code
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: The correct fix is indeed to change message with body: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29

Comment: Hello I have made the change however it is still generating the error.

The Script is set to send emails based on a form which will input the variable data into the spreadsheet. Hence the reason I've taken the time to load each variable and activate the sheet.